# Magento 2: What does the special variable @arguments do in a LESS mixin

Tags: magento2

What does the special variable @arguments do in a LESS mixin

Comment: What command do you need to run when you create a new LESS file?

Comment: What is the most practical way to write this selector in LESS using selector concatenation?

.block__element--modifier

. { 
  { 
   { 
   ... 
  } 
 } 
}

Comment: How do you add a mixin to customize a jQuery UI widget?

var config = { 
 “”: { 
  “”: { 
   “mage/tabs”: { 
    'Vendor_Module/js/tabs-mixin’:  
   } 
  } 
 } 
};